# Setting nested controls in FormArray with FormBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jAHglwQFzFPy69xnFJr4?p=preview):

```
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      foobars: this.fb.array([fb.group({ foo: null, bar: null })]),
      baz: null
    });

    const formValues = {
      foobars: [
        { foo: 1, bar: 'one'}
        { foo: 2, bar: 'two'}
      ],
      baz: 'baz'
    };

    this.form.reset(formValues);
  }

  addFoobar() {
    this.form.controls.foobars.push(this.fb.group({ foo: null, bar: null }))
  }
```

And a template:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let foobar of form.controls.foobars.controls">
    foo: <input [formControl]="foobar.controls.foo" type="number">
    bar: <input [formControl]="foobar.controls.bar">
  </div>
  baz: {{ form.controls.baz.value }}
  <button (click)="addFoobar()">Add foobar</button>
</div>
```

The form is supposed to have variable amount of `foo`/`bar` control pairs. which are stored then as `foobars` array in database and retrieved as a plain object (`formValues` is static in this example, but in reality it is not).

The problem is that `reset` doesn't create nested controls in `foobars` form array automatically, while I would expect that it will.

How can form value be set here with `reset`? Is creating `foobar` item manually as `fb.group({ foo: ..., bar: ... })])` the only correct way to add/set nested controls?

Comment: Because you are setting the values in the constructor, so no need for the markers to be reset too, can't you use setValue() method instead?

Comment: You can't use setValue to set a FormArray, no.

Comment: This is interesting: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10960

Comment: @DeborahK Interesting indeed. The issue looks similarly and it was closed, but it still persists. Guess I'll close the question for now. It likely should be reported instead. Thank you for participating.

Comment: But, setValue() - Sets the value of the FormArray. It accepts an array that matches the structure of the control. I don't say I am right, but more explanation is welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can try to restructure your constructor like:

```
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    foobars: this.fb.array([]),
    baz: null
  });

  this.addFoobar = () => {
    this.form.controls.foobars.push(this.fb.group({ foo: null, bar: null }))
  }  

  const formValues = {
    foobars: [
      { foo: 1, bar: 'one'}
      { foo: 2, bar: 'two'}
    ],
    baz: 'baz'
  };
  formValues.foobars.map(this.addFoobar);

  this.form.reset(formValues);
}
```

1. `foobars` form array is created by *FormBuilder* with empty array
2. `foobars` form array is filled with initial entries using `formValues.foobars.map()` function which executes `addFoobar()` for each iteration.
3. form is updated by executing `this.form.reset(formValues)`

@DeborahK, I disagree with you about

> You can't use setValue to set a FormArray

here is this function: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c59c390cdcd825cca67a422bc8738f7cd9ad42c5/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1221.

On updated plunker I added the button 'Set value for form array' which is enabled when there are exactly 3 array items, clicking the button will update form array with `setValue()` function:

```
setFaValue() {
  this.form.get('foobars').setValue([
    { foo: 10, bar: 'one0'},
    { foo: 20, bar: 'two0'},
    { foo: 30, bar: 'three0'}
  ]);
}
```

updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XALYC8hUxkY0hIJrGLHx?p=preview